# Structured Data Tool not showing rating

Tags: rating, schema.org, rich-snippets

Currently creating a rich snippet tool but the Google Structured data tool won't show the stars in the example. If you look below I should have implemented the rating system correctly with schema.org.

Anybody can give me the right direction for this problem?

[Google Structured Data Testing Tool Result](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.stickerontwerpen.nl/macbook-stickers/1811-angry-birds-macbook-sticker.html&html=)

Comment: did you read this warning?
_Warning: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or review or availability needs to be present_.
you might want to change `hasCurrencyValue` to `price`.

Comment: Thanks, That was the problem. Disabled that module and everything is showing well